# Field Slideshow module in blocks

Tags: entities, blocks, media, javascript

Im trying to create a slide show banner for my home page in Drupal 7. I do not have enough skill to make my own or to edit the PHP, template files or JS.

So far the easiest module I have found to work with is "field slideshow" but I can only work out how to use this in content.

Does anyone know a way to enable this for use in blocks or a way to make a custom content type move to a different place than that of the main content block?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

All modules will need to be have some tradeoff between a simple solution, and a powerful tool. Field slideshow is a relatively simple solution, while [Views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) is a vastly more powerful tool.
Utilizing the power of Views, you have far better control of your slideshow, one example being, that you can easily create blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the Field Slideshow but to find a Slider Module, there is an interesting doc at [Comparison of Rotator / Slider modules](http://drupal.org/node/418616).

I tested another module so I share what I found :
To have a slide show on my frontpage (D7) I used the Views Nivo Slider. With it you can create a View that will display content in a Slide Show. Then you can display the view in a block or in a Content Pane for the Panel Module.. see the Views Nivo Slider project for more details.
This module is in a dev version so there is some issues :

- [Chrome display pacth](http://drupal.org/files/issues/chrome_not_display-1191534-9.patch)
- [Bug fixes patch](http://drupal.org/files/issues/bugfixes-1129444-15.patch)
- [Add loading.gifhttp](http://drupal.org/node/1237882)

Hope this can be usefull even if I didn't know how to configure Field SlideShow

Answer (score 0):

using CCKBlocks you can get your field slide show or any other field as block, which can than be placed through block management page but you may need to hide the field from manage display to avoid duplication.

you can create a node with your field slideshow and than set that as a front page.